# wordpress get_post_meta give only first value

Tags: php, wordpress

I made one custome post in that there is one *custom field* call **_as_roomname**.

I create total 5 custom post and I want to retrive all it's name but I get only first value.

```
function postlogo(){
global $post;
$counting = 1;
$count = 1;
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'casino', 'posts_per_page' => 5 );
$rPosts = new WP_Query($args);

while ($rPosts->have_posts()) : $rPosts->the_post();?>
<h1><?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_id(), '_as_roomname', true);?> Review </h1><?php
$count = $count + 1;    
endwhile;
}
```

**Output**

```
Casino.com Review
Casino.com Review
Casino.com Review
Casino.com Review
Casino.com Review
```

I want this unique name from all post but it give me only first value. How will I get that I don't know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing current post id (`get_the_id()`) in get_post_meta function which seems incorrect. Pass the id of the post you are getting in loop.

```
 get_post_meta($rPosts->post->ID , '_as_roomname', true);
```

Comment: Thanks for your replay Rikesh. I tried that one also but that didn't work. Both code give same output

Comment: Ok can you try `$post->ID` instead of `$rPosts->post->ID`. Also add `global $post;` at top of your while loop.

Comment: Can you debug & check `$post->ID` or `$rPosts->post->ID` are you getting different post id in your loop.

Comment: In both condition I will get different Post Ids. But with `$rPosts->post->ID` it will give me at list first name and with `$post->ID` it show only `Review`.

Comment: Strange than is should come up with different meta values. Are you sure all post have different values in meta field ? Also try adding `wp_reset_query();` after `endwhile;`.

Comment: I got it. Thanks a lot Rikesh. I saw my database and it save the same value in all post in admin panel it's show diff but no Probs I know how to solve that. Thanks a Lot